# Delete elements between two occurrences in list

Tags: list, ocaml

I have to make a function that take a list and return the list but without the elements betweens the occurences.

For example: [**1**; **2**; 3; 4; **2**; **7**; 14; 21; **7**; **5**] -> [1; 2; 7; 5]

I imagined that to make this I will take the head of the list, and then see
if there is another occurrence in the tail, so I browse the list and when I found the occurrence, I delete everything between them and I keep just one of them.

First I tried something like this:

```
let rec remove list = match list with 
    | [] -> []
    | h::t -> if(List.mem h t) then
                (*Here I would like to go through the list element by element to
                 find the occurence and then delete everything between*)
               else
                 remove t
```

So for the part I don't succeed to do, I made a function which allows to slice a list between two given points, just like so:

```
let slice list i k =
   let rec take n = function
     | [] -> []
     | h :: t -> if n = 0 then [] else h :: take (n-1) t
   in
   let rec drop n = function
     | [] -> []
     | h :: t as l -> if n = 0 then l else drop (n-1) t
   in
   take (k - i + 1) (drop i list);;

(*Use: slice ["a";"b";"c";"d";"e";"f";"g";"h";"i";"j"] 2 3;;*)
```

I also have this function that allows me to get the index of points in the list:

```
let index_of e l = 
  let rec index_rec i = function
    | [] -> raise Not_found
    | hd::tl -> if hd = e then i else index_rec (i+1) tl
  in
  index_rec 0 l ;;
(*Use: index_of 5 [1;2;3;4;5;6] -> return 4*)
```

But I don't really know how to combine them to get what I expect.

Comment: What if they are imbricated? for an input like [1; 2; 2; 1]  is it [1; 2; 1] or just [1]? and if you have [1 ; 2 ; 3 ; 1 ; 3 ; 2]?

Comment: Hello, if they are imbricated, like [1;2;2;1], it returns [1], for the second case, it have to return [1;3;2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is what I made :

```ml
let rec remove liste = 
    let rec aux l el = match l with 
    | [] -> raise Not_found
    | x :: xs -> if el = x then try aux xs el with Not_found -> xs 
        else aux xs el in 
    match liste with 
    | [] -> []
    | x :: xs -> try let r = x :: aux xs x in remove r with Not_found -> x :: remove xs;;
```

my aux function return the list which follow the last occurence of el in l. If you have any question or if you need more explanation just ask me in comment

Comment: Hello, first thank your answer. But I don't really understand what ```Not_found -> xs``` do.

Comment: so el = x so we found a bound but maybe there is another one further away in the list so we ``try`` to find another one but if we don't find any we return the result for the last bound we found. Is this clearer? x)

Answer (score 0):

A version that uses an `option` type to tell if an element appears further on in the list:

```ml
let rec find_tail ?(eq = (=)) lst elem =
  match lst with
  | x :: _ when eq x elem -> Some lst
  | _ :: xs -> find_tail ~eq xs elem
  | [] -> None

let rec remove ?(eq = (=)) lst =
  match lst with
  | [x] -> [x]
  | x :: xs -> begin
      match find_tail ~eq xs x with
      | Some tail -> x :: remove ~eq (List.tl tail)
      | None -> x :: remove ~eq xs
    end
  | [] -> []
```

Also lets you specify a comparison function (Defaulting to `=`).

Answer (score 0):

Let's break this down. If we supply a value, can we get the next identical value and the remainder of the list *after it*?

```
# let rec next_and_rest v lst =
    match lst with
    | [] -> None
    | x::xs when v = x -> Some (x, xs)
    | _::xs -> next_and_rest v xs;;
val next_and_rest : 'a -> 'a list -> ('a * 'a list) option = <fun>
```

We can then use this in a `collapse` function. As we iterate through the list, collapsing an empty list obviously yields an empty list. If the list isn't empty, we use `next_and_rest` to find the next occurrence of that value and the rest of the list after it. By getting this "rest" value we can avoid repeating work.

If that function call returns `None`, then we know we should add the current element to the front of the list resulting from the recursive call of `collapse` on the tail of the list.

If it does find a match, then it adds that value to the front of the result of collapsing the list *after* that second occurrence.

*Using `tail_mod_cons` allows this to be a tail-recursive function.*

```
# let[@tail_mod_cons] rec collapse lst =
    match lst with
    | [] -> []
    | x::xs ->
      match next_and_rest x xs with
      | None -> x :: collapse xs
      | Some (y, ys) -> y :: collapse ys;;
val collapse : 'a list -> 'a list = <fun>
# collapse lst;;
- : int list = [1; 2; 7; 5]
```